# Can the idiom "fall off the wagon" be said to be "chiefly American"?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, dialects

I read an answer on another site which referred to the idiom of *falling off the wagon* as being "chiefly American". That got me curious since I would have thought that this particular idiom is shared by both sides of the pond. I tried an NGram of *fall off* vs *drive the wagon*, and could find hits on both their [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall%20off%20the%20wagon%2Cdrive%20the%20wagon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3) and their [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall%20off%20the%20wagon%2Cdrive%20the%20wagon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20off%20the%20wagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrive%20the%20wagon%3B%2Cc0) corpus, but of course that isn't really conclusive as there's no way to compare. There is a hint though as I noticed that there is a clear hike in usage in BrE in the past few years (after 2000), so that could indicate that it used to be less common in BrE.

This makes sense since the idiom itself is [attested from 1904](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wagon#etymonline_v_4787), but it [apparently](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37133/25030) arose in the US during prohibition, so it likely was indeed more common in the US at the turn of the century. Is that still the case today? Can we still say this is "chiefly" an AmE expression or is it now simply an English language one understood and used in both AmE and BrE (and others, presumably) equally?

Updating here to incorporate my comment below:

> I am not distinguishing between [to be] *on the wagon* and *falling
> off the wagon*, I'm asking if the general idiom of *the wagon* meaning
> abstaining from alcohol, be one on it or off it, is more common on
> either side of the pond today.

Comment: It's true the usage [to be] "on the wagon" = "forsworn from alcohol" was *originally* AmE, but there's not much difference today between the usage rate per million written words for [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+on+the+wagon&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) and [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+on+the+wagon&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3). Certainly the difference isn't great enough to justify calling the usage "chiefly American" today. ***Falling off*** the wagon is just a trivial extrapolation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh, yes, I am not distinguishing between [to be] _on the wagon_ and _falling off the wagon_, I'm asking if the general idiom of _the wagon_ meaning abstaining from alcohol, be one on it or off it, is more common on either side of the pond today.

Comment: There's a limit to what you can do with NGrams, but the exact sequence ***fallen off the wagon*** (which has *massively* gained traction over recent decades) is actually slightly more common per million words in the Google Books BrE corpus. And almost certainly the percentage of "false positives" for that search string (contexts involving *actual* wagons, rather than metaphoric teetotal ones) would be higher in the AmE corpus, so it's well within the bounds of possibility that in reality we Brits have pretty much taken over "your" usage (as I recall, you're AmE).

Comment: Eh, I'm squarely in the middle, which is why I cannot really opine on things like this. I grew up speaking AmE (but not living in the US) and have spent around 10 years living in the UK, so I'm all over the place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134294/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-terdon).

Comment: Why don't you ask the person claiming that the expression is a chiefly American usage where they obtained their data?

Comment: I did, but they didn't know for sure, so I figured I'd go for an authoritative answer.

Comment: What's the full name of The Wagon? The Temperance Wagon? The Prohibition Wagon? Whose posters are you looking at?

Comment: @JohnLawler only the idiom itself as it relates to sobriety or lack thereof. Unfortunately, others have decided this is opinion based—which I find quite surprising as it can be conclusively answered if one can actually compare corpora, but so be it—so I guess I will never get an answer.

Comment: You'd need to have records of public and political speech (actual conversations) to see where it came from first, and that would be from a metaphor. Idioms don't invent themselves, and sobriety was a big issue in America, at least, spawning thousands of images, like John Barleycorn and Demon Rum. Look for wagons with human cargo, probly headed for a good place, away from a bad one.

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, there's a nice answer here, which I link to in my question, claiming (plausibly) that it originally referred to a water cart and linking it to prohibition: [Origin of the idiom "falling off the wagon"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37133). So it is indeed plausible  that it was more common in AmE at least at some point.

Comment: Yes, it was "The Water Wagon". I recall the name now. Take The Pledge to drink only water and get on the water wagon, which is, needless to say, Bound For Glory.

Comment: Why was this closed as opinion based? The OP is not asking for an opinion. nGrams may be difficult to interpret but it is not an opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It would stand to reason that fallen off the wagon is "slightly more common ... in the BrE corpus"; Americans are much more likely to eschew the perfect and use the simple past. BrE: I have fallen off the wagon again. AmE: I fell off the wagon again.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I just checked Google NGrams in more detail. It's true that the sequence ***fell off the wagon*** is about 10% more common than ***fallen off the wagon*** in AmE (they're about equally common in BrE). But I can only compare the different corpuses in the actual NGram charts - if I try to "drill down" to the actual data, NGrams just shows the same "English" data regardless of whether I started from an AmE or BrE chart. And only 2 of the first 10 hits for ***fell...*** are even metaphoric at all, whereas all but 2 of the first 10 ***fallen...*** are for *exactly* this "ex-TT" sense.

Comment: ...anyway, [***here's***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+on+the+wagon%3Aeng_us_2019%2CI%27m+on+the+wagon%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) a chart showing that ***I'm on the wagon*** (which will almost *always* be for the metaphoric sense we're looking at here) has apparently been more common in the Google NGrams ***British*** English corpus over the last decade or two.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize false positives (such as things literally falling off a wagon), I used the term *go on the wagon*, which will usually have alcohol involved. (I included *go*, *goes*, *going*, *gone*, and *went*.)

Here are results from the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the British National Corpus, which each cover roughly 1990–2019:

Corpus of Contemporary American English:

[`GO on the wagon`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=104587760) (15 results, 2 of which are from books)

British National Corpus:

[`GO on the wagon`](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=104587703) (3 results, all of which are from books)

In this Google Ngram, I overlaid the American corpus results with the British ones for `go on the wagon` 1930–2019:

[image: A Google Ngram]

What to conclude? *Chiefly* an American English expression might be a bit of an overstatement, though it doesn’t seem have a lot of traction in the British world at large.

Comment: I'm confused. This seems not to answer the question at all. Did you suppose that "go on the wagon" is what the OP was actually asking about, or was the opposite of what he actually did ask about just easier for you to research?

Comment: @Robusto: OP clarified in a comment under the question: "I am not distinguishing between [to be] on the wagon and falling off the wagon, I'm asking if the general idiom of the wagon meaning abstaining from alcohol, be one on it or off it, is more common on either side of the pond today." It is certainly easier to research *go on the wagon*, for the reason I mentioned.

Comment: It might be relevant to mention that the British National Corpus is about one tenth the size of the Corpus of Contemporary American English - 100+ million for the BNC vs 1.1 Billion for COCA. Also, as far as I'm aware, the lastest version of the BNC was released in 2007.

Comment: Worth mentioning, but a factor of 10 in 100 million is statistically insignificant for extrapolation.